# Bounding boxes are not drawn even both classification and localization loss is near 0: TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

#### System information

```
* **Linux Ubuntu 16.04**:

* **TensorFlow installed from source**:

* **TensorFlow version 1.12.0**:

* **CUDA/cuDNN version : 410.86**:

* **GPU model : 1080Ti**:
```

#### Describe the problem

I am training object detection algorithm using TensorFlow object detection API.

Config File: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config

My Config File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oOqvTyZDWtECWPo_5qYgUsOgZMwAVDlk

Model Name: SSD_resnet50_v1_fpn

After training model using object detection API for around 100000 global steps, total_loss goes to zero. Classification and Localization loss also goes to zero as shown in Tensorboard
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FMEyC2pt5Ud-4CJGzN0HTO55MzrN2mHX

But evaluation on test images does not perform well and draw any bounding boxes.
Below is the tensorboard for evaluation
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aseVoKWQMjFC2N0X437DnBRIJej3xXYn

I have checked multiple times for the correctness of data, everyting is right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you trained for 10k steps, not for 100k (x10 because of batch size, so 100k examples, but not 100k steps).
As you can see by the learning rate plot, you only passed by 5k the warmup (where there's positive slope). I suggest you either let the training session continue until the learning rate is significantly lower, e.g. finishing the 50k (the number set in the config file). In case you don't want to wait that long/the training set is not that large, you can instead modify the `num_steps` in `train_config` and `total_steps` in `optimizer` to the number you want, e.g. 10k. Don't forget to modify the `warmup_steps` accordingly, e.g. to 1/10 of `total_steps`. I also suggest trying a smaller initial learning rate, e.g. 0.01, and most importantly - to give the regularization smaller weight/give the classification and localization larger weights, since it looks like the regularization overwhelms your loss.